# I used bezier curves and circles to make a shape, how do i transform it in to an editable object?

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

I used a bezier curve and a circle to make a claw shaped thingy around the bezier curve, I want to be able to edit the geometry of this shape, but don't know how to transform it in to an object.

Answer (score 1):

menu bar > *Object > Convert To > Mesh From Curve*.

[image]

Comment: thanks man, was really struggling.

Comment: @moonboots I was just wondering, and feel free to tell me to mind my own business, why you don't seem to up-vote questions you answer?

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean, am I supposed to upvote them? sometimes I do when it's a non too common one but maybe I don't do what I'm supposed to